# Использование .NET библиотеки в .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть библиотека на .NET 6.0, я хочу использовать ее в приложении на .NET Framework 4.7.2. Как я могу это сделать? Просто создать зависимость на .dll не получается - отлетает с "Не удается загрузить файл или сборку" при запуске

Comment: Зачем вам .NET Framework? Он уже умер, забудьте про него. | Библиотека ваша? Исходный код имеется? Перекомилируйте под .NET FW (подправив где нужно). Или переделайте её под [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Comment: Эти фреймворки несовместимы. А Framework 4.x действительно умер, от старости.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил воспользоваться советом не использовать .NET Framework и жить действительно стало легче